# Low frame rate in viewport even in an empty scene

Tags: performance

I have a 144 hz monitor, and few days ago I noticed that Blender started to run noticeably slower than what I was used to, even when I wasn't doing anything unusual.

I recently upgraded my computer, and although since then I did not had a lot of time to use Blender, I don't think the frame rates were off when I was briefly testing some stuff, but it is possible that I just simply missed it.

I tried a lot of solutions already: restarting PC, reinstalling Blender, updating drivers, factory resetting Blender and its preferences, but to no avail. Verifying files (I use Blender 4.0 on Steam) caused a download of 1 file and increased the average frame rate from ~30 to ~80, but that's about it. I couldn't find anyone else with my exact problem.

I downloaded an fps monitoring add-on for the debugging purposes, and it shows the bizarre fps behaviour I'm experiencing.

I should also add that games and other programs run completely fine.

GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6750 XT

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X

[image]

EDIT: There doesn't seem to be anything helpful in the System tab in Preferences.

Comment: If it were me, I would poke around in Edit->Preferences->System and see what I could see.